# Unknown option 'pdflatex' for package xcolor. \edef

Tags: color

I have created some slides for teaching a course using

```
\documentclass[xcolor=pdflatex,dvipsnames,table,10pt]{beamer}
```

I am using texstudio. After updating miktex I am getting the following error

```
Unknown option 'pdflatex' for package xcolor. \edef (in line 266 of xcolor.sty)
```

Any suggestions to to resolve the issue?

Many thanks in advance
Dimitris

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Why do you use pdflatex as option for xcolor? What should it do?

Comment: `xcolor` does not provide an option `pdflatex` (and AFAIR never did). It does provide an option `pdftex`, but you should not use it, because `xcolor` can detect the engine drivers (`pdftex`, `xetex`, `luatex`, `vtex`) itself using `color.cfg`. [Using the wrong driver (e.g. when switching to LuaLaTeX) would even result in errors.](https://github.com/latex3/graphics-cfg/pull/3) So just removing `xcolor=pdflatex` and *not using `xcolor=pdftex` is recommended*.

Comment: there is no such option in xcolor,  there is only the option pdftex (and it is not needed to set that as pdftex/pdflatex is detected automatically)

Comment: It would be better to use `\documentclass[xcolor={dvipsnames,table},10pt]{beamer}` so that `dvipsnames` and `table` only get passed on to xcolor instead of all packages.

Comment: Many thanks! I used \documentclass[xcolor={dvipsnames,table},10pt]{beamer} and now everything works great!

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz as a side remark: with a current xcolor you could also simply do `\usepackage[table,dvipsnames]{xcolor}` in the preamble, that will activate the options too.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer You should get some display which counts how many option clash errors this avoids - I bet the numbers would go up fast :)

Answer (score 0):

I checked with TeX Live from 2012 up to 2024 (to be released today 2024-03-13) and the error message started to be issued with TL 2023.

In the previous releases it did nothing at all and I believe it's good that it issues an error now, because the option is invalid.

The correct specification should be

```
\documentclass[xcolor={dvipsnames,table},10pt]{beamer}
```

Comment: Many thanks! I used \documentclass[xcolor={dvipsnames,table},10pt]{beamer} and now everything works great!